# When is the database informed about a transaction from Java?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions

I'm interested in knowing when exactly does Java communicate to the database that a transaction has been created. When setting autocommit to false in JDBC or creating a @Transactional method in Spring, when exactly does the communication with the database occur to inform it of the transaction change?

A little background to the question:
I have a method that will be called billions of times:

```
@Transactional
void addData(Object[] data);
```

Now this method doesn't actually persist data into the database but stores it in a buffer. When the buffer overflows, the method flushes all the data to the database in a batch update.

This means that if the method is called a billion times - it actually persists the data to the database a hundred thousand times or so.
But does this mean that for every call of this method Spring will contact the database to create a SAVEPOINT or begin a transaction or something?
Or will that information be piggied back on the first flush to the database?

My concern is that I do not want this method to cause 2 billion database requests with a transaction status update (one for transaction start, one for transaction end).

Also will a transaction commit (in the sense of an actual database request) occur if no data was flushed to the database?

Comment: Spring doesn't communicate anything what and when depends on your persistence situation. But spring starts a transaction at the start of that method and ends it on the end of the method call. Or when there already is a transaction it does nothing and piggy backs on that existing transaction.

Comment: I understand that. My question is if when Spring starts a transaction, is that information then, at that moment sent to the database? Does a database request at that exact moment occur? Will there be real physical traffic in that moment? Or will it never happen as long as there is no flush to the database?

Comment: That depends on your persistence provider. But what use would a transaction be if that would only be active on a flush. How would you obtain a lock on a record if there isn't a transaction? So generally a start of a transaction is also going to inform the database about that.

Comment: I'm using pure JDBC. As to your comment - I can easily imagine that the transaction will actually start just prior to the first database operation being performed. Or that the table/rows/row-ranges are being locked only immediately before the first sql operation. What I need is certainty whether this is the case or that the locks occur immediately after the transaction creation.

Comment: Those are different beasts... But generally nothing will be locked before you issue select queries, and even then it depends on your isolation level, your database (is it going to do row lock, table lock, page lock, or ....) and how you write your queries. So it depends, basically there is no easy straightforward answer...